# How to add additional attribute to an id in element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes, setattribute

Couldn't find here at Stackoverflow.

How can I add *additional* attribute to an element?

I need this

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

to be

```
<div id="test test2"></div>
```

`document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("id", "test2")` sets to

```
<div id="test2"></div>
```

EDIT: the question provided was different question and not about class.

Comment: You can't with ID. Id is a single word and has to be unique to your document. See the docs at the [mozilla dev network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Comment: @scrappedcola, how to add it to `class` then?

Comment: `document.getElementById("test").className += " test2"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an element's class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to read the attribute by using the `getAttribute` and then con-cat the new value at the end like this:

```
document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("id", document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("id") + " test2")
```

**EDIT**

Just keep in mind to avoid doing this with the ID attribute. You can do it with almost any other attribute though.

**Example with the class attribute**

```js
document.getElementById("test1").setAttribute("class", document.getElementById("test1").getAttribute("class") + " test2class")
```

```css
.test {
  color:black;
}

.test.test2class {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1" class="test">This is a test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually you are not looking to add a new attribute, you are looking for a way to change the value of an attribute that is already exists.

The `setAttribute` function can do this for you:

```
document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("id", document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("id") + " test2")
```

(After running this code you will get `id="test test2"` on your element).

> Note that specifically the `id` attribute **should not** contain spaces